# Can closed unit ball be a retract of unit sphere?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, retraction

Let $B^3$ denote the closed unit ball in $\Bbb R^3$ and $S^2$ be the unit sphere. Does there exist a retraction $r$ from $B^3$ onto $S^2$?

I cannot argue it using fundamental group since both have the trivial fundamental group. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean "Let $B^3$ denote the closed unit ball in $\Bbb R^3$ and $S^2$ be the unit sphere. Does there exist a retraction $r$ from $B^3$ onto $S^2$?"?

Comment: Yeah @Lord Shark The Unknown I have rectified it.

Comment: No, by the "no-retraction theorem" (equivalent to the Brouwer fixed-point theorem). Use either $H_2$ or $\pi_2$ in place of $\pi_1$.

Comment: Then how do I prove Brouwer's fixed point theorem in higher dimension if I assume it first?

Comment: Do you mean "Can unit sphere be a retract of closed unit ball?"?

Comment: Yes. I mean just that.

Comment: Instead of $\pi_1$ you need to use $\pi_n$ or some other algebraic invariant, e.g. (co)homology in $n$-th dimension. For $n=2$ it gives your result. There's no shortcut: Brouwer's fixed point theorem in $n$-th dimension is not a consequence of $n-1$ dimension. At least not in a trivial manner.

Comment: Who was the person who edited my comment above?

Answer (score 1):

A standard way of doing this is via homology.  Namely, if there exists a retract $r: B^3 \to S^2$, then $r \circ i = \text{Id}$ (with $i: S^2 \to B^3$ inclusion).  In particular, one looks at: 
$$\mathbb{Z} = H_2(S^2) \xrightarrow{i_*} H_2(B^2) \xrightarrow{r_*} H_2(S^2) = \mathbb{Z}$$ 
and notes that the composition should be the identity map, but $H_2(B^2) = 0$, a contradiction.  This generalizes for any $n$-ball and its boundary sphere.

Comment: I haven't read homology till now. I will accept your answer as soon as I will read it. Please keep on waiting till then.